# How to trigger an event with newVal in CanJs

Tags: canjs

I am stuck while trying to trigger a `CanJs` event with `newVal`.I have a change event like below:

```
"{ApplicationShell.AppState.processState.modelExecution} change": function (model, ev, attr, how, newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal === "Something"){
  }
}
```

So here i have to trigger this event. I can trigger this event using below code:

```
can.trigger(ApplicationShell.AppState.processState.modelExecution,"change")
```

But i couldn't pass a value to `newVal` of the changed event. I tried to pass like below:

```
can.trigger(Sentrana.ApplicationShell.AppState.processState.modelExecution,"change","abcd");
```

But this "abcd" is passed to the `attr` of the event method not in the newVal parameter.

**So is there any way to pass value to the newVal using can trigger?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah we can send value to the newVal using can.trigger().

```
can.trigger(ApplicationShell.AppState.processState.modelExecution,"change",["a","b", "c", "d"])
```

**Now the values will go the trigger event like below:**

> "a" -> attr 
>  "b" -> how 
>  "c" -> newVal 
>  "d" -> oldVal